# numpy savetxt - ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead

Tags: python, numpy, csv

Attempting to save two numpy array values to a csv, but, getting an error.

```
profit_value = cumulative_profits[-1] - cumulative_profits[insample] # For this example, consider profit_value = 0.15093565  profit_value is of type <class 'numpy.float32'>

date_value = x_dates[insample]  # For this example, consider date_value = 2017-02-01 22:52:00 and is of type <class 'numpy.str_'>

with open("modelout.csv", "ab") as csvfile:
    np.savetxt(csvfile, date_value, delimiter=",")
    np.savetxt(csvfile, profit_value, delimiter=",")
```

The error is:

> ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead

Any ideas of a workaround or how this might be fixed?

Comment: A starting point is to read the `savetxt` docs.  This function is designed to write a `csv` file - a table with neat columns and rows.  That's why it expects a 2d array.  And numeric with the default `fmt`. You apparently are trying to write a single value.  It doesn't matter than the type is `np.float32`.  It is still a single value, with shape ().  Why are you using `savetxt`?

Comment: Hi! I'm attempting to do a sliding window, multiple runs, of this script. It is a time series of values, date_value is the datetime stamp and profit_value is the dollars (float) for the datetime stamp.  Each run of the script I'm trying to append to the csv one datetime stamp and one float value. Both date_value and profit_value are set from different numpy values, which is why I've been trying to use savetxt.

Comment: You can write strings and floats to a text file without using `savetxt`.  The fact that they come from arrays doesn't matter.  `savetxt` iterates through its **array** argument, and does a `f.write( fmt % tuple(row))`, that is, it formats the row and writes it to the file.  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Since the numpy arrays only have one value each, there is no need to iterate when outputing to the csv (therefore, not use numpy savetxt). I placed the single values into a list and wrote out to a csv (appending to last time run). This worked:

```
import csv

profit_value = cumulative_profits[-1] - cumulative_profits[insample] 
date_value = x_dates[insample] 

meta_out = [date_value, profit_value]
with open('modelout.csv','a', newline='') as fd:
   writer = csv.writer(fd, delimiter=',')
   writer.writerow(meta_out)
```